# How do I make JScrollPane scroll to follow input focus?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a Swing app with a large panel which is wrapped in a `JScrollPane`. Users normally move between the panel's subcomponents by tabbing, so when they tab to something out view, I want the scroll pane to autoscroll so the component with input focus is always visible.

I've tried using [`KeyboardFocusManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html) to listen for input focus changes, and then calling [`scrollRectToVisible`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#scrollRectToVisible%28java.awt.Rectangle%29).

Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) displaying my current strategy (just copy/paste and run!):

```
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FollowFocus {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

      public void run() {
        final int ROWS = 100;
        final JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setLayout(new BoxLayout(content, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        content.add(new JLabel(
          "Thanks for helping out. Use tab to move around."));
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
          JTextField field = new JTextField("" + i);
          field.setName("field#" + i);
          content.add(field);
        }

        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
                            .addPropertyChangeListener("focusOwner", 
                     new PropertyChangeListener() {

          @Override
          public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if (!(evt.getNewValue() instanceof JComponent)) {
              return;
            }
            JComponent focused = (JComponent) evt.getNewValue();
            if (content.isAncestorOf(focused)) {
              System.out.println("Scrolling to " + focused.getName());
              focused.scrollRectToVisible(focused.getBounds());
            }
          }
        });

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Follow focus");
        window.setContentPane(new JScrollPane(content));
        window.setSize(200, 200);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

If you run this example, you'll notice it doesn't work very well. It does get the focus change notifications, but the call to `scrollRectToVisible` doesn't appear to have any effect. In my app (which is too complex to show here), `scrollRectToVisible` works about half the time when I tab into something outside of the viewport.

Is there an established way to solve this problem? If it makes any difference, the Swing app is built on Netbeans RCP (and most of our customers run Windows).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My comment to the other answer:

> scrollRectToVisible on the component itself is the whole point of that
>   method ;-) It's passed up the hierarchy until a parent doing the
>   scroll is found

... except when the component itself handles it - as JTextField does: it's implemented to scroll horizontally to make the caret visible. The way out is to call the method on the field's parent.

**Edit**

just for clarity, the replaced line is

```
    content.scrollRectToVisible(focused.getBounds());
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for the explanation. Your proposed fix didn't work in my app (though it worked like a charm in the example above), but after a bit of experimentation I found the following to work: `((JComponent) focused.getParent()).scrollRectToVisible(focused.getBounds())` Now, nobody breathe or the focus follower breaks... ;)

Comment: @gustafc your answer should be correct answer, thanks for help even 11 years later :D

Comment: @Szprota21 Haha, happy to help! I still remember how horrible this was trying to fix  but all respects due kleopatra without whom I hadn't fixed this

Answer (score 3):

you have to take `Rectangle` from `JPanel` and `JViewPort` too, then compare, for example

notice (against down-voting) for final and nice output required some work for positions in the `JViewPort`

```
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.*;
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245328/how-do-i-make-jscrollpane-scroll-to-follow-input-focus
public class FollowFocus {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                final int ROWS = 100;
                final JPanel content = new JPanel();
                content.setLayout(new BoxLayout(content, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
                content.add(new JLabel(
                        "Thanks for helping out. Use tab to move around."));
                for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
                    JTextField field = new JTextField("" + i);
                    field.setName("field#" + i);
                    content.add(field);
                }
                final JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(content);
                KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().
                        addPropertyChangeListener("focusOwner", new PropertyChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                        if (!(evt.getNewValue() instanceof JComponent)) {
                            return;
                        }
                        JViewport viewport = (JViewport) content.getParent();
                        JComponent focused = (JComponent) evt.getNewValue();
                        if (content.isAncestorOf(focused)) {
                            System.out.println("Scrolling to " + focused.getName());
                            Rectangle rect = focused.getBounds();
                            Rectangle r2 = viewport.getVisibleRect();
                            content.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(rect.x, rect.y, (int) r2.getWidth(), (int) r2.getHeight()));
                        }
                    }
                });

                JFrame window = new JFrame("Follow focus");
                window.setContentPane(new JScrollPane(content));
                window.setSize(200, 200);
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                window.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: no, you dont need a) any additional rectangle manipulation b) final field

Comment: have to retreat a bit on b) - the reference to content is not needed for scrolling, it's needed for checking if the focused is in content's child hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

Here my short summary. 
Add this to your Tools class:

```
public static void addOnEnter(Component c, Consumer<FocusEvent> onEnter) {
    FocusListener fl = new FocusListener() {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            onEnter.accept(e);
        }
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {  }
    };
    c.addFocusListener(fl);
}

public static void scrollToFocus(FocusEvent e) {
    ((JComponent) e.getComponent().getParent()).scrollRectToVisible(
            e.getComponent().getBounds());
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Tools.addOnEnter(component, Tools::scrollToFocus);
```

component can be JTextField, JButton, ...

Answer (score 0):

One major issue in your code is:

```
focused.scrollRectToVisible(focused.getBounds());
```

You are calling scrollRectToVisible on the component itself! Presumably a typo.
Make your JScrollPane a final variable and call

```
scrollPane.getViewport().scrollRectToVisible(focused.getBounds());
```

Comment: scrollRectToVisible on the component itself is the _whole point_ of that method ;-) It's passed up the hierarchy until a parent doing the scroll is found

Comment: @kleopatra I did not know that. The change I proposed works fine but I have not idea why it does not work as it is.

Comment: see my answer as to the why (did notice the type of component only after posting the comment) Nevertheless, _do not_ message the viewport directly for code sanity

Answer (score 0):

Here jtextbox is the component you want to focus and jscrollpane is your scrollpane:

```
jScrollpane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(jtextbox.getLocation().x);
```